# pygame - What is the code for clicking on an image

Tags: python, pygame

I'm adding a title screen to my game, and I want to add "play" button that will launch the main game when the user clicks it.

I have everything set up, but I'm not sure what the command is to have the mouse interact with the play button image.

First, I have the play button image loaded outside of the main loop

```
play = pygame.image.load("play.png").convert()
```

Then, I have it blit on the screen, with a rectangle behind it as a marker

```
play_button = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [365, 515, 380, 180])
screen.blit(play, [350, 500])
```

Comment: Perhaps this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636250/python-pygame-how-do-i-know-if-a-mouse-clicked-on-an-image

Comment: `PyGame` is low-level library - you have to do it on your own.

Answer (score 4):

`PyGame` is low-level library - it has no GUI widgets and you have to do many things on your own.

It is easier to create class `Button` and then use it many times.

Here example with class `Button`. When you click it change color.

`event_handler()` checks button click.

```
import pygame

# --- class ---

class Button(object):

    def __init__(self, position, size):

        # create 3 images
        self._images = [
            pygame.Surface(size),    
            pygame.Surface(size),    
            pygame.Surface(size),    
        ]

        # fill images with color - red, gree, blue
        self._images[0].fill((255,0,0))
        self._images[1].fill((0,255,0))
        self._images[2].fill((0,0,255))

        # get image size and position
        self._rect = pygame.Rect(position, size)

        # select first image
        self._index = 0

    def draw(self, screen):

        # draw selected image
        screen.blit(self._images[self._index], self._rect)

    def event_handler(self, event):

        # change selected color if rectange clicked
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # is some button clicked
            if event.button == 1: # is left button clicked
                if self._rect.collidepoint(event.pos): # is mouse over button
                    self._index = (self._index+1) % 3 # change image

# --- main ---

# init        

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,110))

# create buttons

button1 = Button((5, 5), (100, 100))
button2 = Button((110, 5), (100, 100))
button3 = Button((215, 5), (100, 100))

# mainloop

running = True

while running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # --- buttons events ---

        button1.event_handler(event)
        button2.event_handler(event)
        button3.event_handler(event)

    # --- draws ---

    button1.draw(screen)
    button2.draw(screen)
    button3.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()

# --- the end ---

pygame.quit()
```

https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/pygame/button-click-cycle-color/main_class.py

[image]